# Как доработать код программы управляющей списком дел?

Tags: java, массивы

Получил тоже самое задание с массивами в Java, которое разбирали ранее на этом сайте.

[Разработайте программу — список дел, который управляется командами в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1416417/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8)

Там Дмитрий выкладывает рабочий код. но мне его нужно доработать, что бы он выводил в консоль комментарии после ввода туда команд. Кто-то скажет, - это проще простого, но мне знаний не хватило нормально их прописать, ниже прикладываю условия этих комментариев, может, кто подскажет как их правильно прописать в этом коде, код этот написал не я а пользователь Дмитрий.

Примеры работы со списком дел (жирным шрифтом выделен ввод пользователя)

**ADD buy milk** Добавлено дело "buy milk"

**ADD learn java** Добавлено дело "learn java"

**LIST** 0 - buy milk 1 - learn java

**EDIT 0 make a cup of tea** Дело "buy milk" заменено на "make a cup of tea"

**DELETE 1** Дело "learn java" удалено

**LIST 0** - make a cup of tea

**DELETE 100** Дело с таким номером не существует //

Вывод в консоль комментариев к List, ADD и Delete, я прописал но комментарии к EDIT и к DELETE(если указан не существующий индекс), не смог нормально, может подскажите как это реализовать?

Класс TodoList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class TodoList {

    private final List<String> todoList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String todo) {
        todoList.add(todo);
    }

    public void add(Integer index, String todo) {
        if (exist(index)) todoList.add(index, todo);
        else add(todo);
    }

    public void edit(Integer index, String todo) {
        if (exist(index)) todoList.set(index, todo);
    }

    public void delete(int index) {
        if (exist(index)) todoList.remove(index);
    }

    public String list() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < todoList.size(); i++) {
        sb.append(i).append(" - ").append(todoList.get(i)).append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();

    }

    private boolean exist(Integer index) {
        return index != null && index >= 0 && index < todoList.size();
    }
}
```

Класс Main:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        TodoList todoList = new TodoList();
        
        while (true) {
            UserInput userInput = parse(scanner.nextLine());
            switch (userInput.getCommand()) {
                case "LIST":
                    System.out.println(todoList.list());
                    break;
                case "ADD":
                    todoList.add(userInput.getIndex(), userInput.getTask());
                    break;
                case "EDIT":
                    todoList.edit(userInput.getIndex(), userInput.getTask());
                    break;
                case "DELETE":
                    todoList.delete(userInput.getIndex());
                    break;
            }

        }

    }

    private static UserInput parse(String input) {
        String[] split = input.split(" ");
        if (split.length == 1) return new UserInput(input.toUpperCase(), null, null);
        try {
            return new UserInput(split[0].toUpperCase(), Integer.valueOf(split[1]), String.join(" ",
                    Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 2, split.length)));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return new UserInput(split[0].toUpperCase(), null, String.join(" ",
                    Arrays.copyOfRange(split, 1, split.length)));
        }
    }

    private static class UserInput {

        private final String command;

        private final Integer index;

        private final String task;

        public UserInput(String command, Integer index, String task) {
            this.command = command;
            this.index = index;
            this.task = task;
        }

        public String getCommand() {
            return command;
        }

        public Integer getIndex() {
            return index;
        }

        public String getTask() {
            return task;
        }

    }
```

После моих исправлений (их в этом коде нет), только команды LIST и ADD правильный комментарий выводит в консоль, а вот edit  и delete(с несуществующим индексом), я нормально даже прописать не смог

Comment: Подредактировал вопрос согласно правилам сайта, приветствия и короткие ссылки тут не нужны. Для домашних заданий тоже действуют особые правила https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic и пользователи оценивают ваши старания, прежде чем дать или не дать ответ - поэтому зря вы убрали свои доработки.

Comment: А так вам надо если и не написать, то хотя бы разобраться в том, как работает код Дмитрия и что он вообще делает. У вас есть четыре входа в нужные вам методы. Если вы разобрались с тем, чтобы вывести в консоль часть из list и add, то в методах edit и delete советую обратить особое внимание на `exist(index)` и все-таки понять, как это работает. Подсказка - вам понадобится ветка else для несуществующих индексов.

Comment: Да спасибо за ответ, ниже я прикладываю свою доработку метода add, при которой комментарий выводится в консоль согласно заданию. 
  Так же приложу и edit, но в нем я не пойму что писать в первых кавычках (как сослаться на ту строку массива которую меняем)  что касается delete, то честно говоря я пытался добавить условия if и else, по принципу если индекс существует то выводим в консоль текст - "Дело "текст задачи" удалено" , а иначе выводим в консоль текст - "Дело с таким номером не существует", но толком нечего не получилось.

Comment: ```  
 case "ADD":
                    todoList.add(userInput.getIndex(), userInput.getTask());
                    System.out.println("Добавлено дело "  + '"' + userInput.getTask() + '"');
                    break;

                case "EDIT":
                    todoList.edit(userInput.getIndex(), userInput.getTask());
                    System.out.println("Дело " +  " не знаю как сослаться на меняемую строку массива " +
                            "заменено на " + '"' + userInput.getTask() + '"');
                    break;    

 ```

@Alex Krass

Comment: Я прочитал рекомендацию по написанию кода в комментарии, но так и не смог его нормально выложить, получилось как получилось((

Comment: Как создатель, вы можете отредактировать свой ответ, просто добавив нужно ниже. Комментарии для кода не очень хорошо подходят.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае используется коллекция ArrayList и её интерфейс List. Перед тем, как использовать данный код, вам хорошо бы узнать о них. Тогда будет понимание, что тут происходит.

Допустим отсюда: https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questsyntaxpro.level12.lecture02

Список создается в самом начале и указывается, что в нем будут храниться строки.

```
private final List<String> todoList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Согласно описанию, у нас есть несколько методов, которые позволяют работать со списком. Основные это добавление элемента в список add, изменение элемента set, удаление remove, и получение get.

Если вы хотите писать в switch-case, то класс TodoList требует доработки вида, чтобы вы могли получать значения из списка по индексу и проверять существует ли оно вообще:

```
public class TodoList {
    ... прочие методы класса ...

    public boolean hasIndex(index) {
        return exist(index);
    }
    
    public String get(index) {
        if (exist(index)) {
            return todoList.get(index);
        } else {
            return null; // В вызываемом коде потенциальный NullPointerException
        }
    }
}
```

Проще сделать в самом TodoList, тогда код выше не понадобится.

```
public class TodoList {
    ... прочие методы класса ...
    ... рассмотрим только edit и delete ...
    
    public void edit(Integer index, String todo) {
        if (exist(index)) {
            // получаем имя по индексу, которое сейчас хранится
            String oldName = todoList.get(index); 
            // заменяем на новое
            todoList.set(index, todo);
            // выводим логирование
            System.out.println("Дело " + oldName + " заменено на " + todo);
        } else {
            // тут элемента по индексу не существует
        }
    }

    public void delete(int index) {
        if (exist(index)) {
            String oldName = todoList.get(index);
            todoList.remove(index);
            System.out.println("Дело " + oldName + " удалено");
        } else {
            // тут элемента по индексу не существует
            System.out.println("Дело с таким индексом не существует");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да большое спасибо  за потраченное время и столь грамотный ответ, теперь все комментарии выводятся как в задании.  автотесты правда не проходит, как-то мне надо теперь этот код адаптировать под автотесты. Материал перечитаю , который вы скинули, но я уже изучал видео и вебинар по этой теме, и прямо скажу без практики мало, что в голове оседает, скомканная в 5 месяцев теория по всей Java, оставляет пробелы, тем более много сил уходит на основную работу.

@Alex Krass